# Error de sintaxis (ERROR 1064 (42000)) al intentar usar mysqlslap

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos en MySQL llamada *jugos_ventas* y quiero usar mysqlslap sobre la tabla *facturas* para medir el tiempo de consulta bajo cierta carga, pero al usar exactamente la misma sintaxis que el instructor del curso me aparece un error de sintaxis. He buscado por todas partes cuál es dicho error ya que el mensaje es muy ambiguo. Abajo pongo el código:

> mysql> mysqlslap -uroot -p --concurrency=100 --iterations=10 create-schema=jugos_ventas --query="SELECT * FROM facturas WHERE FECHA_VENTA = '20170101'";

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlslap -uroot -p --concurrency=100 --iterations=10 create-schema=jugos_ventas' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

El problema es simple: estoy tratando de ejecutar `mysqlslap` dentro del cliente de línea de comandos de mysql, que lanza tus comandos al servidor y se usa para hacer consultas y ejecutar otros comandos SQL. Por ello el *prompt* es `mysql>`.

Pero `mysqlslap` no es un comando de SQL o reconocido por el servidor, es un programa ejecutable que tienes en tu máquina.

Para ejecutarlo debes salir del cliente de mySQL con el comando `quit` para volver a la línea de comandos del sistema (CMD).

Allí el *prompt* cambiará, por ejemplo a `c:\users\vrivera>` o `/home/vrivera>` (por poner ejemplos).

Debes ir a la carpeta dónde está el ejecutable usando `cd` y desde allí puedes ejecutar el comando tal como lo muestras en la pregunta.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.